# How to get the product of all the elements of a matrix with exact decimal points without rounding off in R?

Tags: r

I previously used the prod() function in R that can give me the product, and it works fine for big numbers. The numbers I have are too small like 1.294528e-07 and once I take the product it gives me a 0. How can I get the accurate product with exact decimal numbers?

Comment: `options(digits=10)`

Comment: You have a PC in front of you who "talks" binary, you rarely will get "exact decimal numbers". If you try `.Machine$double.xmin`, you'll see the closest to zero number that R can represent. Anything smaller is zero.

Comment: maybe multiply all numbers by for example 10^7 before getting the product ?

Comment: ...or taking `sum(log(x))` (if `x` is your vector) and then working with the log of the value instead of the value itself. OP, you should provide a little bit of context of what you are trying to do to receive a proper solution.

Comment: @CathG : But not all numbers have an exponent 7. It can go from 3 to 10 or may be more.  I will not be sure because it is a big matrix of 16,000 columns of which I'll need the product of every column.

Comment: You can see what the minimum is to decide by which number you should multiply your numbers, although it would also be "dangerous" if the product becomes too big... did you try to multiply by 10^7 to see what you get ?

Comment: The minimum is 4.881414408e-07. This is about 1 column, I have 16,000 such columns with different minimums. I tried multiplying with 10^7 as below and got big numbers but when I take the product of it I get "inf".   R code:  > phi_inpower7=phi_in*(10^7)  
> prod(phi_inpower7)  
[1] Inf

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [`Rmpfr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html):

```
x <- 1.294528e-07;
x^100;
## [1] 0
library('Rmpfr');
mpfr200 <- function(...) mpfr(...,precBits=200);
x <- mpfr200(1.294528e-07);
x^100;
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits
## [1] 1.6260909947893069252110098843324246495136887016336218206204661e-689
```

Or you could try using big rationals from [`gmp`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html), although that can get unwieldy fast:

```
library('gmp');
x <- as.bigq(1.294528e-07);
x^100;
## Big Rational ('bigq') :
## [1] 863201774730415899361077141424209396921125795515936990572548766128423810485376236957138978501283812494839104247698243918794530436552717763753923415271480284747830193402522833445368586578235815336302329397252055448087703163456038666698935354732741208048881276922439385153961853551463063865863458552423073323374618023089542368149617965922293453325011050815707644365808660423522776994133587512616070446174486428153909409377712433145387919387175172482342168167092570331925560436171324785600650158865676862026009729048525389272889703709380624434349438465164559591242984791355618727989751127260257309242805499481511142165616784856784942417419338154196561431152388897904866047119736434465720555151366859879507712533271194851766672024261634534292974370183919317337519761869292257947511511111895425764926171263133863980854536246390233199502174749146911367500644673909293464659053254182209374190247093969004854275674922622004129684228283369400286413197699863545912211106461047595912964876198783114172495242447965086668614473659343976994896679029656266765528726921384485164153780083326552118475505412074971594197272427677831237385443579950907872485700396062323506489811292749356021319775368577664875790645937426179486396681942844892307294288187671687510056569029216067321069225537944854772595983467728588640812585079820715315382504185719050646602130250650306723313760231069912835376365077115331890400516502810239814459239282321065702537572103441710647744406489548580900916084596895906189449738524638127337711843685456775272799845630310027842996833372802952394634016929280394482001/53084469288402965415857953902888840109250315594591772197851276288408082158869345776872184284291470495326835835491268017776297213098616208286592801322449982740570898437845767564651639451594841758957168240360072929342348878909784083488070009533176658698675760470010215436132534526706916446032842195249059760060209393388578176281027744679436285035293376786965957429093838689438026612141820062960073237944227430409290082873605748455349816343081466372681612738552636294666573661997989000563367893746123926316870120929629731301360766711677076606816082939449299471019533119911247114865751561110071173719092050562287666719013887097553109594042589835370732409680749273477741701995190365166750190649349508586781414000112900259875654673888811075100415790235930270448790550846107436360615795146817327563001398966815753145995110673462134196824939359497706430237425390060733252224220979131253874493851823165781457427314551881655553433521397260371393668335053627112038905459972042994824319713601980913921755210218082851146588240382210406887660412630451416112206306502796230074832738884324233514086958873577398927563897852887699678587467916741882087729456997268017154775450070371874680332524775280043635270781581135769020865808796073362505082201497885288236887117727248916243704472117062440908853938749830047482062530807255930310025959255017626077608884577821899189515192765061903944746945679900747890669013446056647522960607623949336195016784356934505954115977283306997415274187752372480232652878520163417566097389917356958213807994947634794209832173114356392822435844256992216702376456519427913660058510779720382422426729352627871147386069533497741201545766859622239986052843328404669795291152396764393702113455439610494964706121896827191760262984304690887475635610694078746800875955908479469409563047706020039725815572087005410536948676710051947334063697608908539017716795313119629533327813992071776512146390147185444968042597376280912548998385218672413833388480083312283356458666501168482077474943858309275329657545594008977132937574085616539588927255406484838471048801662983695044651588178399267847057683205128610922849562650411762874243138435345707386259866513245949164125352989897783775852403441398200260025840304184956928642989258546038224598392605412214974894309376
```

(Notice the slash at character 1570 into that digit sequence.)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.   I tried using the Rmpfr.  Here's what I got with phi_in being a column of decimal digits with different precisions of which I need a product   > mpfr200 <- function(...) mpfr(...,precBits=20)  
> x <- mpfr200(phi_in)  
> prod(x)  
1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits  
[1] 1.4366828091542774e-4763

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. I could not get the linebreak with 2 spaces working.